# "unexpected EOF while parsing" in a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, syntax-error, eof

For this project, I was trying to make a list that contained all the distances between all the points that I had in a list(I have a list of x coordinates and one of y)

```
for da in range(len(meta.values())):
    for db in range(len(meta.values())):
        dis.append(math.sqrt((x[db] - x[da])**2 + (y[db] - y[da])**2)
```

print(dis)

However, this part of it either gives me an "unexpected EOF while parsing" or an "invalid syntax" by the print statement. I cant see the mistake here can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unmatched parantheses in `dis.append(...`

it should be:

`dis.append(math.sqrt((x[db] - x[da])**2 + (y[db] - y[da])**2))`